# regular expression to match alphabets or numeric or spaces

Tags: java, regex

can somebody help me with a regular expression whichreturns true only if the string has alphabets or alphabet with spaces.. the string can have numbers or alphabets or alphabets with spaces.

this is what i have tried

```
/^[ a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: `/^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+$` Use `\s` for all space characters. Also, add complete and relevant code in question

Comment: Add valid and invalid examples in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
[\p{Alnum} ]+
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
NODE             EXPLANATION
---------------  ------------------------------------------
[\p{Alnum} ]+    any character of: letters and digits, ' '
                 (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                 possible))
```

Additionally, if you plan to use the regular expression very often, it is recommended to use a constant in order to avoid recompile it each time, e.g.:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("[\\p{Alnum} ]+");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = ...

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()
    );
}
```